# Deploying after Post Build Script

Tags: tfs, msbuild, webdeploy

I am using TFS and webdeploy to build and deploy my code. Some of the projects I have have a post-build script in their Build Events tab in their properties.

The problem is that TFS, when running the build definition, builds, then deploys, then run the post-build script. It happens in that order.

Is there a way to force TFS to build, run the post-build script, and then web-deploy? (in that order)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way to use the post-build script like your asking.  Instead you could add some MSBuild script in your wpp.targets file to achieve the same result. For example,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Target Name="AfterBuild" BeforeTargets="MSDeployPublish">
    <Message Text="Post build, pre deploy logic goes here" />
    <Exec Command="ver" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```